# OData v4 unbound function with custom routing

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-routing, odata-v4

I have created a "Utilities" controller that is not bound to any model and contains only unbound functions.
I would like to be able to call this through a url like the following:
**odata/Utilities/SomeMethod()**

Right now I have to call it like the following:
**odata/SomeMethod()**

How do I create a custom route for "utilities"?

I have tried:

```
[ODataRoutePrefix("Utilities")]
public class UtilitiesController : ODataController
```

I have also tried:

```
[ODataRoute("Utilities/SomeMethod()"]
public string SomeMethod()
```

But both of these throw an error:
"The path template 'Utilities/SomeMethod()' on the action 'SomeMethod' in controller 'Utilities' is not a valid OData path template. Resource not found for the segment 'Utilities'."

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default controller selector to achieve this. You can create a new class that inherits from `DefaultHttpControllerSelector` like this:

```
public class CustomControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
{

    public override string GetControllerName(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        string controllerName = null;
        // I haven't tested this, but here you can decide whether you want to 
        //  route to your new controller or not
        if (request.ODataProperties().Path.PathTemplate == "~/UnboundFunction")
        {
            controllerName = "UtilitiesController";
        }
        else
        {
            controllerName = base.GetControllerName(request);
        }

        return controllerName;
    }
}
```

And then you can replace the controller selector like this:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new CustomControllerSelector());
```

This lets you choose which controller to use at runtime for every request

Comment: This does not work. If you try to call in the url "/odata/Utilities/SomeMethod()" you will get a 500 Internal Server Error.  If you try to call "/odata/SomeMethod()" then it will go into the CustomControllerSelector but once in there, it does not route to the correct controller. You will get "No type was found that matches the controller named UtilitiesController". The controller does exist. Also, this still would not let you have "/odata/Utilities/SomeMethod()" which is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define the controller class:

   ```
   public class UtilitiesController : ODataController
   {
       [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
       [ODataRoute("SomeMethod")]
       public string SomeMethod()
       {
           // add your code
       }
   }
   ```
2. Map the route:

   ```
   var config = new HttpConfiguration();

   var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

   modelBuilder.Function("SomeMethod").Returns<string>();

   config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata/Utilities", modelBuilder.GetEdmModel());
   ```

Comment: This will modify all of the current OData routes. I only want to add a new custom route for the Utilities controller.